# How to rotate a Sprite around the circle in LibGDX?

Tags: java, libgdx, image-rotation

I want to rota a sprite around a circle, but I couldn't do that. If I could not tell my problem you can understand from this picture:

[image: square rotating around circle]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Sprite` has a method `setOrigin()`, https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/graphics/g2d/Sprite.html#setOrigin-float-float-

Set `Sprite`'s origin at the center of your circle and rotate it. Code will look similar to this:

```
float circleCenterX = ...;
float circleCenterY = ...;
float angle = ...;
Sprite sprite = ...;

sprite.setOrigin(circleCenterX, circleCenterY);
sprite.rotate(angle); // or sprite.setRotation(angle);
```